# Depending on the tag is there a possibility to know on which days and hours are there more answers?

Tags: support, statistics

Is there a way to know on which days and/or hours a question tagged (x...y...z) is more likely to get answered?

This is motivated by my recent question. I would like to know whether I've post it on the "appropriate" day of the week and time.

What does your experience tells you?

Comment: For maximum exposure, I would post a question during the morning (I am in UTC+0) so as to catch the Europeans first and the North Americans later. This seems to be where most of the people are most of the time.

Comment: @PeterPhipps: Thanks for the information.

Comment: This information is not easily accessible (even by the moderators). If you find a SQL wizard somewhere, you may be able to play with the [data explorer to find something out](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63782/tags-activity-over-time).

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks! With [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/63782/tags-activity-over-time?TagName=divergent-series) I got a table with the following data: 7, 2011, 5; 4, 2011, 6; 4, 2011, 8; 1, 2011, 9; 7, 2011, 10; 12, 2011, 11; 2, 2011, 12; 4, 2012, 1; 4, 2012, 2; 1, 2012, 3

Comment: @WillieWong. And this result of a query on "real-analysis" tag on the same site: 7,"2010","7"; 47,"2010","8"; 35,"2010","9"; 54,"2010","10"; 86,"2010","11"; 59,"2010","12"; 77,"2011","1"; 51,"2011","2"; 110,"2011","3"; 91,"2011","4"; 87,"2011","5"; 106,"2011","6"; 78,"2011","7"; 110,"2011","8"; 144,"2011","9"; 213,"2011","10"; 249,"2011","11"; 185,"2011","12"; 208,"2012","1"; 271,"2012","2"; 153,"2012","3".

Comment: @Americo: too bad I am no SQL wizard. I am thinking of the possibility of running the query based on UTC time instead of year-month.

Comment: It may be possible to combine the link in my previous comment with [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63660/questions-by-time-of-day-and-day-of-week) to get a "by time of day and day of week" traffic analysis for individual tags

Comment: @Willie: I will explore your idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. I was bored for about 15 minutes, so here goes. Try [this database explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/revision/65085/69147/tag-frequency-by-time-of-day-and-day-of-week) query.

For example, for [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis) the most favourable is wednesday, thursday, and friday late afternoons (16.00 - 20.00 in some timezone [see caveats below]).

Some caveats:

- I don't know what time-zone the time of the day is computed. It is in 4-hour long blocks. Presumably based in UTC or some American timezone.
- It is currently sorted in reverse order by frequency. So scroll down to see the "most favourable time and day of week" for a given tag.
- I don not guarantee that the script actually does what I think it does.

Comment: That's fine to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per Willie Wong's comment I got these results for [Tags activity over time](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63782/tags-activity-over-time) in table format.

- For the (divergent-series) tag $\quad$ 
  7, "2011", "5"; 4, "2011", "6"; 4, "2011", "8"; 1, "2011", "9"; 7, "2011", "10"; 12, "2011", "11"; 2, "2011", "12"; 4, "2012", "1"; 4, "2012", "2"; 1, "2012", "3".
- For the (real-analysis) tag $\quad$ 7,"2010","7"; 47,"2010","8"; 35,"2010","9"; 54,"2010","10"; 86,"2010","11"; 59,"2010","12"; 77,"2011","1"; 51,"2011","2"; 110,"2011","3"; 91,"2011","4"; 87,"2011","5"; 106,"2011","6"; 78,"2011","7"; 110,"2011","8"; 144,"2011","9"; 213,"2011","10"; 249,"2011","11"; 185,"2011","12"; 208,"2012","1"; 271,"2012","2"; 153,"2012","3".

The details do not include the time, as far as I understand. However it is a part  of what I had in mind when I asked the question.

In the meantime Willie Wong posted another idea to be explored.

Added. The "[Tag frequency by Time of Day and Day of Week](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/revision/65085/69147/tag-frequency-by-time-of-day-and-day-of-week)" is obtained as per Willie Wong's answer, which seems enough for the purpose of my question. See his answer.

Edit to add. For the (calculus) tag I ran a query in  "Tag frequency by Time of Day and Day of Week". The plot is this one.

[image]